# Difference between @size(max = value ) and @min(value) and @max(value)

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I want to do some domain validation. In my object I have one integer.

Now my question is: if I write

```
@Min(SEQ_MIN_VALUE)
@Max(SEQ_MAX_VALUE)
private Integer sequence;
```

and

```
 @Size(min = 1, max = NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
 private Integer sequence;
```

If it's an integer which one is proper for domain validation?
Can anybody explain me what is the difference between them?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your reason for using different constants? Why using NAME_MAX_LENGTH instead of the above used SEQ_MAX_VALUE in this question?
If there is non, I would recommend using the same as to not distract from the core of the question.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

`@Min` and `@Max` are used for validating numeric fields which could be `String`(representing number), `int`, `short`, `byte` etc and their respective primitive wrappers.

`@Size` is used to check the length constraints on the fields.

As per documentation `@Size` supports `String`, `Collection`, `Map` and `arrays` while `@Min` and `@Max` supports primitives and their wrappers. See the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/).

Answer (score 25):

```
package com.mycompany;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Car {

    @NotNull
    private String manufacturer;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
    private String licensePlate;

    @Min(2)
    private int seatCount;

    public Car(String manufacturer, String licencePlate, int seatCount) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.licensePlate = licencePlate;
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
    }

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

`@NotNull`, `@Size` and `@Min` are so-called constraint annotations, that we use to declare constraints, which shall be applied to the fields of a Car instance:

`manufacturer` shall never be null

`licensePlate` shall never be null and must be between 2 and 14 characters long

`seatCount` shall be at least 2.

Comment: OP is asking about `@Size` applied to an `Integer`, I think that's the point of his confusion. Is it even legal to apply it to an integer? It might have the semantics similar to those in an RDMS -- digit count.

Comment: can u pls tell me difference between @size(max = value ) and @min(value) @max(value)

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-builtin-constraints) I get the impression that in your example it would be intended to use:

```
@Range(min= SEQ_MIN_VALUE, max= SEQ_MAX_VALUE)
```

> Checks whether the annotated value lies between (inclusive) the specified minimum and maximum.
> Supported data types:
>
> BigDecimal, BigInteger, CharSequence, byte, short, int, long and the
> respective wrappers of the primitive types