# OpenAPI validator rules to use max instead of size

Tags: java, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I have following model in my contract descriptor

```
BaseGroup:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          pattern: '^\p{Alnum}+$'
          maxLength: 50
```

which generates

```
public class BaseGroupDto   {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
  */
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
  @NotNull
  @Pattern(regexp="^\\p{Alnum}+$") 
  @Size(max=50) 
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
...
}
```

is it possible somehow configure openapi generator to use `@Max` instead of `@Size` for length check?

I use this maven plugin to generate DTOs

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>               
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.4</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Related: [Difference between @size(max = value) and @min(value) @max(value)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11189398/113116)

Answer (score 1):

With the javax validation @max means max value not the max size